Limiting number of Game Object
So I have this script that summons a stationary laser that the player is supposed to not get hit by, but since there's multiple game object with the code and they can all trigger at making it overwhelming to dodge I wanted to limit the amount that can be spawn at once (for example once 2 laser have activated a third one cant activate until one disapears)
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyLazrWarning : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject lazr;
    public GameObject lazrWarning;
    public Transform lazrPos;
    public movement player;
    public time waves;
    private float timer;
    private float m_FireTime = 1f;
    private float minFireDelay = 7f;
    private float maxFireDelay = 12f;
    private float warning;

    void Start()
    {
        this.m_FireTime = (float)Random.Range(this.minFireDelay, this.maxFireDelay);
        lazrWarning.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (player.gameStarted && waves.currentTime>0f)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;    
            if(timer > m_FireTime) 
            {
                lazrWarning.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                warning += Time.deltaTime;
                if(warning > 2)
                {
                    timer -= this.m_FireTime;        
                    this.m_FireTime = (float)Random.Range(this.minFireDelay, this.maxFireDelay);
                    shoot();
                    lazrWarning.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    warning = 0;
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    void shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(lazr, lazrPos.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```


Under the assumption that I want that count to be global and I am never going to have multiple counts that are relevant in different contexts, I would solve this with a static variable on a script on the "Lazrs" themselves.
A static variable is a variable that is shared by all instances of a class and can be accessed without requiring any specific instance by simply using the name of the class in place of a variable holding a reference to an instance.
public class Lazr : MonoBehavior {

   public static int Count = 0;

   void Start() {
       Count++;
   }

   void OnDestroy() {
       Count--;
   }      
}

This will increase the Lazr.Count by 1 whenever a Lazr is being instantiated (or at the start of the scene when there are already Lazr's as part of the scene). It will reduce the Lazr.Count by 1 whenever a Lazr is destroyed (including once for each existing Lazr when the scene is unloaded). So it will always maintain the count of the Lazr's in the scene.
You can then access this value in any other script like this:
if (Lazr.Count <= 2) {
   Instantiate(lazr, lazrPos.position, Quaternion.identity);
}


Thanks, this was a nice and simple way to fix the problem and was able to modify it so that the warning stops appearing when there's two laser

Thank you for the help

I would solve this by having a central manager script that takes care of the total amount of things that can spawn per level. This has the advantage that each of your spawner scripts only needs to be aware of the manager and does not need to know about other spawners.
A manager is usually a good choice when you have some central logic or elements that are used by a lot of things. An example would be a tracker of your points or level progress. While you could store it as well as part of your player, things like level game logic (in your case total amount of lasers) does not really belong as part of your player.
I prefer a system of one MasterSingleton and task specific singletons that hold information/ logic for what they are needed. This is what the view in the inspector looks like, each child would be its own manager. There are other versions of singletons in far greater detail discussed here: In Unity, how do I correctly implement the singleton pattern?


public class MasterSingleton: MonoBehaviour {
    
    public static MasterSingleton Instance { get; private set; }
    public SpawnManager SpawnManager { get; private set; }
    public SoundManager SoundManager { get; private set; }
    
    private void Awake() {
        if (Instance != null && Instance != this) {
            Destroy(this);
            return;
        }
        Instance = this;
        SpawnManager = GetComponentInChildren<SpawnManager>();
        SoundManager = GetComponentInChildren<SoundManager>();
    }
}

public class SpawnManager: MonoBehaviour {

    public int maxLasersAllowed;
    public int currentLasersSpawned;
    public GameObject laserTurret;

    public void TryToSpawnLaser(Transform transform) {
        if (currentLasersSpawned< maxLasersAllowed) {
             Instantiate(laserTurret, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
             currentLasersSpawned++;
        }    
    }

    public void ReduceTurrentCount() {
        currentLasersSpawned--;
    } 
}

The code for your shoot method would look like this now.
shoot() {
     MasterSingleton.Instance.SpawnManager.TryToSpawnLaser(transform);
}

When you destroy the laser, you should not forget to call the function for reducing the count as well. You could add some listeners / events to handle that as well.

Soooo some questions and issues, pretty much the issue I'm currently having with this that the laser is not spawning in the right spot in fact they all spawn in the same spot and also I have vertical and horizontal laser so is there a way to specify this one spawn this laser here vertically and this on spawn laser like this

Except that this is working great thanks for the help

Sure, if the rotation for your object is important, all you need to do is add the rotation you need in the call of TryToSpawnLaser and modify it inside.
